# Getting specific row from a list fails

Tags: python

This is the API output:

```
{
    "resultLength":133710,
    "resultList" : [
            {
            "date" :  1510872659568,
            "requestParameters" : [
              "datesAsStringsFormat=dd-MMM-yyyy",
              "datesAsStrings=true",
              "outputFormat=xlsx",
              "requestId=14e7aa1f-680f-49d0-8e76-cfd797b9b6b6"
            ],
            "score" :  1,
            "totalRequestTime" :  1261,
            "userId" :  167895
            },
            {
            "date" :  1510872659679,
            "requestParameters" : [
              "datesAsStringsFormat=dd-MMM-yyyy",
              "datesAsStrings=true",
              "outputFormat=xlsx",
              "requestId=14e7aa1f-680f-49d0-8e76-cfd797b9be78"
            ],
            "score" :  1,
            "totalRequestTime" :  1255,
            "userId" :  452669
            }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to extract the requestId for each userId, however for some reason I am not able to. This is what I tried:

```
req = requests.get(url=url, auth=(user,password))
out = req.json()
results = out['resultList']

solr_df = pd.DataFrame()
for record in results:
    requestId = pd.DataFrame(record['requestParameters'][3],columns=['requestId'])
    df = pd.DataFrame(requestId)
    df['userId'] = record['userId']
    solr_df = solr_df.append(df)
```

However it throws a `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`
Can you assist with rectifying the error?

If it too hard to only extract the requestId row for each requestParameter, perhaps you can assist instead removing all rows that aren't requestId related after the for statement runs?

***Edit:***

When I run it for `record['requestParameters']`, it runs succesfully but it extracts all rows of requestParameters per userId.

I just tried slicing as such: `portfolioId = pd.DataFrame(record['requestParameters'][-1:0])` and **it did** return results (unlike a single index call), however it was for both outputFormat and requestId rows. 
I then tried `portfolioId = pd.DataFrame(record['requestParameters'][1:2])` and it returned results for both requestId and datesAsStrings.

It looks like requestParameters rows are not indexed consistently (not sure why it is possible), is there still a way to get a specific row from a list?

Thank you

Comment: Try printing the arguments you're passing to `DataFrame` before calling it.

Comment: If I only do record['requestParameters'] then it runs without error, but it just prints every line from requestParameters for each userId. However, I only want requestId

Comment: You have two variables named `df`.

Comment: @Barmar why does that matter? I am just stating the definition of df later on. The error occurs before it even gets to evaluating the second df

Comment: `df = df.append(df)` did you really intend to append something to itself?

Comment: I'm not saying this is the cause of the problem, it just seems suspicious.

Comment: @Barmar, I understand now- sorry no youre right, it doesnt make sense to do that- in my script it is solr_df=solr_df.append(df) I just renamed it when postiing the question here. Fixed to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question; because the rows in requestParameters are not properly indexed (an explanation as to why that can happen would be great), I had to extract all rows from requestParamters, filter only for those including requestId, and then extracting everything after "=".

```
solr_df = pd.DataFrame()
for record in results:
    df = pd.DataFrame(record['requestParameters'],columns=['requestId'])
    df['userEmail'] = record['userEmail']
    solr_df = solr_df.append(df)

solr_df = solr_df[solr_df.requestId.str.contains('requestId')] 
solr_df['requestId'] = solr_df['requestId'].str.split('=').str.get(1)
```

Comment: This is a sort of a work-around, if somebody has a solution to pull variables out of a list when they don't have a consistent index (sometimes index 1 and something index 3), or based on value in row, that would be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

```
req = requests.get(url=url, auth=(user,password))
out = req.json()
results = out['resultList']

df = pd.DataFrame()
for record in results:
    requestId = pd.DataFrame({"requestId": record['requestParameters'][3]})
    df = pd.DataFrame(requestId)
    df['userId'] = record['userId']
    df = df.append(df)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Answer (score 0):

To extract the id, you can try this:

```
req = requests.get(url=url, auth=(user,password))
out = req.json()
results = out['resultList']
ids = [i["requestParameters"][-1] for i in results["resultList"]]
```

Output:

```
['requestId=14e7aa1f-680f-49d0-8e76-cfd797b9b6b6', 'requestId=14e7aa1f-680f-49d0-8e76-cfd797b9be78']
```

Or, if you just want the numerical value:

```
import re
req = requests.get(url=url, auth=(user,password))
out = req.json()
results = out['resultList']
final_val = [re.findall('(?<=requestId\=)[\w-]+', i["requestParameters"][-1])[0] for i in results["resultList"]]
```

Output:

```
['14e7aa1f-680f-49d0-8e76-cfd797b9b6b6', '14e7aa1f-680f-49d0-8e76-cfd797b9be78']
```

Comment: For some reason this returns the whole requestParameters field, and not just the row indexed at -1

Comment: @user8834780 is the API data you posted above stored as `results` from: `out = req.json()`;
`results = out['resultList']`?

Comment: yes, that's correct. results=req.json()['resultList']

Comment: @user8834780 My apologizes. I made several changes, and it works for me. Please try and let me know.

Comment: Sorry I may have confused you- out['resultList'] gives everything that is inside resultList. I dont have access to a computer, but if we do results['resultList'] I expect it will throw an error because this is basically doing out['resultList']['resultList']

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try parsing your json string in Json Editor Online(http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)? It might help you if your json string is valid or not.

You are missing a comma after 12th line (`"totalRequestTime" :  1261`). I think that might be the very first problem.

Comment: I am not missing a comma in the API output, just a bad copy paste. Fixed. and API is valid,  
If I only do record['requestParameters'] then it runs without error, but it just prints every line from requestParameters for each userId.